# How to show informations in graphs using jsp and CanvasJS?

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets, canvasjs

I need to draw graphs with my sql server data .

So I have my servlet that select all data I need and transform it to json , then I forward all data to my jsp.

what I want is to show information like names in my pie graph .

this is my servlet :

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("select SUM(ChiffreAffaire)as CA,M500_NOM from V502_client where Annee=?  and Mois=2 group by M500_NOM");
            ps.setString(1, name);
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

    while(resultSet.next()){
        yVal = resultSet.getFloat("CA");
                nom=resultSet.getString("M500_NOM");
        map = new HashMap<Object,Object>(); map.put("x", nom);map.put("y",yVal); list.add(map);
        dataPoints = gsonObj.toJson(list);
    }  

            request.getSession().setAttribute("data", dataPoints); 
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("graph.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

and this is the script to show my graph :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%     String shared1 = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("data");%>

window.onload = function() { 


var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Représentation graphique"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
        showInLegend: "true",
        startAngle: 40,
        dataPoints: <%out.print(shared1);%>
    }]
});
chart.render();
}
</script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height:370px; width:600px;"></div>
```

The result of this is shown like :

[image: The result of this is shown like :]

I want to be like this :
[image]

Comment: This may help: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-pie-chart/

Comment: I already see this article but couln't adapt it to my code ; well data for ex  that I forward from servlet to jsp is like :  [{"x":3EG "y":2280.0 "} {"x":3EG "y":4200.0 }] How can I have the name 3EG in my graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define `legendText` on your dataset and indicate, which property contains the label ('x' in your case).

```
data: [{
    type: "pie", 
    showInLegend: true,
    legendText: "{x}", 
    startAngle: 40,
    dataPoints: <%out.print(shared1);%>
}]
```

> Please note that every label (`x` property) should be different for a `pie` chart.

Comment: If i write y it shows me the result but with x wich is name i got nothing (no graphs)

Comment: No error It s working fine with {y} i don't know why {x} doesnt show

Comment: Your data `[{"x":3EG "y":2280.0 "} {"x":3EG "y":4200.0 }]` is not valid JSON format, this must be the reason. `3EG` must be enclosed by double-quotes and there are commas missing.

Comment: so what should I do please

Comment: produce valid JSON data, i.e. `[{x: "label 1", y: 2280.0 }, {x: "label 2", y: 4200.0 }]`

Comment: I though it s what I done  in my servlet .Isn't it ???dataPoints = gsonObj.toJson(list);  In my servlet is json format [{"x":"3EG","y":4800.0}]  so my problem is in my jsp file??

Comment: In your last comment, JSON looks fine, this was not the case in the comment you added underneath your answer.